# What are the options for euthanasia in countries like India?

Tags: euthanasia

We have a number of questions about stray dogs in India, and it appears that [Stray Dogs in India Are a Menace](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/08/07/world/asia/india-stray-dogs-are-a-menace.html).  In the United States, stray dogs are mostly captured, assessed, cared for in a humane way and either found homes or euthanized. The same system also provides a location to take animals, where the hard decisions can be made by others, if re-homing or euthanasia is the best choice.

In countries like India, where stray are problematic and there is not infrastructure in place to address the issue, what options exist for a  concerned individual to euthanize a dog?

Comment: @RamKeswani This very greatly depends from city to city and on the locality. Where I live, stray animals are taken care of very well. Saying people consider it a fundamental duty to hurt stray animals is a very gross and inaccurate exaggeration.

Comment: @rahuldottech Sir please watch https://youtu.be/hdiWVmFTVj4 . I mentioned 'most' sir. I have read cases of people cutting puppy's paw, burning puppies alive, etc. I know there are good people like you sir, but we must accept that more than half people are cruel to them. Almost everyday I see people throwing stones at dogs, kicking pups. I have even seen accidents. I estimated that 90% of puppies born die within their first 3 months. I deleted the comment sir. I might have exaggerated, but no one can deny that more than half of people in India abuse animals once in a life.How do you learn code?

Answer (score 1):

Here in India, people can be very religious and euthanizing would probably lead to a lot of unnecessary debate and nothing good would come out of it.

Here's what happens in my neighbourhood:

1. Someone complains about the stray dogs.
2. If enough complaints are registered, a government van turns up in about a week.
3. All adult male dogs are captured. (Younger dogs are left alone)
4. They are neutered.*
5. They are turned loose on the streets, often in the same neighbourhood.

---

*I'm not sure whether or not the females are spayed but I don't think so...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, If the females are not spayed it's not a very effective solution.  One male can impregnate all the females, and you still have a bunch of puppies.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Agreed. Also, as JustDoIt points out, euthanizing is pretty much illegal here. Citizens, however, often adopt stray dogs as their own and (in most cases) get them neutered or spayed...

Comment: I thought I was referencing an article related to the subject, but it was talking about human euthanasia. That's why I deleted my answer. I wasn't paying attention

Comment: @JustDoIt never mind, it's illegal for animals as well...

Comment: The females are spayed as well. The municipality here works as less as possible which can be used to say that they did something. Some of the males and females in my locality are spayed and neutered.